# Joint pmf of binary random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I want to find the joint pmf of the 3 random variables below:

$$P_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z) = 
\begin{cases}
       {\frac{3}{16}} &\quad\text{if }(x,y,z)\in \{001,111\}\\
       {\frac{1}{8}} &\quad\text{if }(x,y,z)\in  \{000,010,100,110\}\\
       {\frac{1}{16}} &\quad\text{if } (x,y,z)\in  \{011,101\}
        \\ 
     \end{cases}$$

Obviously i know how to find each pmf but the thing that confuses me a lot and i couldnt manage to find anything on internet , is the limits . I don't understand what $(x,y,z)\in \{ 001 , 111\} $ actually means.

Can someone explain?
Thank you.

Comment: It means, for instance, that $P(X=0, Y=0, Z=1)=\frac3{16}$, where $X,Y,Z \in \{0,1 \}$

Comment: $(x,y,z)$ does take the values $(001)$ or the values $(111)$. The probability in both cases is $\frac3{16}$ each.

Comment: So , how can i find py(y) for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can look where $y=0$ and $y=1$ at $(x,y,z)$.

$y=\color{blue}0: (0\color{blue}01), (0\color{blue}00), (1\color{blue}00), (1\color{blue}01)$. The corresponding probabilities are $\frac{3}{16}, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{16}$

$y=\color{Orange}1: (1\color{Orange}11), (0\color{Orange}10), (1\color{Orange}10), (0\color{Orange}10)$. The corresponding probabilities are $\frac{3}{16}, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{16}$

The sum of all probabilities must be 1. This is one property of a probability mass function (pmf). Since the values for $y=0$ and $y=1$ are equal we can deduce that $P(Y=0)=0.5$ and $P(Y=1)=0.5$. Alternatively you can sum up the probabilities. Thus the pmf is for $Y$ is

$$f_Y(y)=\begin{cases} 0.5, \ y=0   \\ 0.5, \ y=1 \\ 0, \ \textrm{elsewhere}  \end{cases}$$

Comment: i did excactly the same for x and y . Is it possible that all the pmfs are the same ? 0.5 for x,y,z=0 , 0.5 for x,y,z=1 and 0 elsewhere.

Comment: @ΓιάννηςΓιαννάκος Yes, $X,Y,Z$ have all the same (marginal) pmf.

Comment: ok thank you a lot!

Comment: @ΓιάννηςΓιαννάκος You´re welcome.